# How to get text of div by id in variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string variable called the res.
Within this variable there is HTML code.
Each Div in variable within the has a id.

```
var res = "<div id="1">1</div>
<div id="2">12</div>
<div id="3">123</div>
<div id="4">1234</div>";

var content-div-1 = ??;
var content-div-2 = ??;
var content-div-3 = ??;
var content-div-4 = ??;
```

I would like to give the id of div and give me values of inside Div.

Comment: You have two choices: Parse the HTML, or get the browser to parse it for you (optionally via jQuery) and then get the result from the resulting disconnected DOM tree.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder Can `gEBI()` find an unappended element?

Comment: @Teemu: I wouldn't use `getElementById` here. (And no, if the element isn't in the DOM, `getElementById` won't find it.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The question has been answered, but there's an alternative without jQuery

```
var res = '<div id="1">1</div>'+
          '<div id="2">12</div>'+
          '<div id="3">123</div>'+
          '<div id="4">1234</div>';

function findMe(txt, id){
    var matches = txt.match(new RegExp('<div\\s+id="'+id+'">[\\S\\s]*?<\\/div>'), 'gi');
    if(matches) return matches[0].replace(/(<\/?[^>]+>)/gi, '');
    return '';  
}

var content1 = findMe(res,1);
var content2 = findMe(res,2);
var content3 = findMe(res,3);
var content4 = findMe(res,4);
```

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/philip100/owa12z6b/)

Answer (score 1):

As you've tagged your question `jquery`, I assume this is in a browser context (or some other context with a DOM). If so, the simplest way to is to parse the HTML and use the resulting disconnected DOM tree:

```js
var res = '<div id="1">1</div>' +
'<div id="2">12</div>' +
'<div id="3">123</div>' +
'<div id="4">1234</div>';

var parsed = $(res);
var contentDiv1 = parsed.filter("[id=1]").text(); // See note below
snippet.log("1: " + contentDiv1);
var contentDiv2 = parsed.filter("[id=2]").text(); // See note below
snippet.log("2: " + contentDiv2);
// ...and so on (or use a loop)
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Script provides the `snippet` object, see http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/242144/134069 -->
<script src="http://tjcrowder.github.io/simple-snippets-console/snippet.js"></script>
```

---

Note: Although `id` value starting with digits are valid HTML, it's awkward to use them because in a CSS `id` selector (`#foo`), you can't start the ID value with an unescaped digit (e.g., `#1` is an invalid selector). That's why I've had to use the attribute selector `[id=1]` above. You can work around it with escaping, but by far the best option is just to not start ID values with digits in the first place.

Comment: It must be inside a loop to iterate over all the elements. Right?

Comment: @Superman: You could loop, or just write the statement four times.

Comment: In our language: دمت گرم <br />
I was stuck badly.<br />
Thanks a lot<br />